# Enable webfont.svg compression in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, svg

I'm working on optimizing my website's load time. One of the suggestions given by Google's PageSpeed is:

[image]

As far as I can tell this should be enabled though. Here's my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule playlist/* /

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset utf-8 .css .js

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(svg)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Defining MIME types to ensure the web server actually knows about them.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/javascript          js
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject   eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf          ttf ttc
    AddType font/opentype                   otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff         woff
    AddType image/svg+xml                   svg svgz 
    AddEncoding gzip                        svgz
</Ifmodule>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compressing output.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text/ text/html text/plain text/xmk text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
</Ifmodule>
```

Is this something which needs to be configured outside of the htaccess file? Or do I have a setting incorrect? I'm exceedingly new to working with htaccess files.

Comment: Nope! My htaccess file is still the same as above. Ho hum.